# Why use this strange variant of package name?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Could someone explain me for which goals programmers use this variant "package name" like in that file [SQLite.pm](https://github.com/dbsrgits/dbix-class/blob/master/lib/DBIx/Class/SQLAHacks/SQLite.pm) from DBIx::Class module?
Full listing:

```
package # Hide from PAUSE
  DBIx::Class::SQLAHacks::SQLite;

use warnings;
use strict;

use base qw( DBIx::Class::SQLMaker::SQLite );

1;
```

Why the name of package is written on other line after 'package'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perl doesn't care about whitespace and comments between `package` and the package name, but the [PAUSE](http://pause.perl.org/) indexer does.  It won't index packages that look like that.  The DBIx::Class folks don't want that class indexed.

Another (more standard) way of doing this is the [`no_index` key](https://metacpan.org/module/CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec#no_index) in the META.json or META.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

it's legal syntax and I assume that PAUSE (the site the CPAN authors use for uploads) does some checks that this construct avoids